# Как установить изображение с сервера в ImageView

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, которое получает некий json массив. Создал свой адаптер, парсю Json и вывожу все в список. Работает нормально. Но вот добавил я поле `link_img` и получаю ссылку на изображение. Так же создал `ImageView` в адаптере, только вот как присвоить ему изображение. Допустим json вернул нам *http://мойсайт/картинки/картинка1.jpg*. Если перейдете по ссылки в браузере то откроется изображение, а вот как передать этот путь в `ImageView`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20load%20image%20from%20url%20into%20imageview&es_th=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этих целей лучше всего использовать библиотеку [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) или [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), так как они не только предельно облегчают получение изображения с сервера, но и кэшируют его, что избавляет от необходимости каждый раз скачивать его заново. Это положительно сказывается на производительности.

[Сравнение эффективности](http://habrahabr.ru/post/218453/) предложенных библиотек

Answer (score 0):

1. Скачиваете файл в телефон, на папку в флешке к примеру.
2. Отображаете на ImageView уже локальный рисунок.

Если нужно без скачивание попробуйте это

```
// show The Image
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
            .execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class));
    finish();

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

только не забудьте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Можно реализовывать без скачивания?? планируется много картинок

Comment: без скачивания в активити для каждого рисунка  - только расширением класса ImageView, где придётся использовать тоже скачивание )))

Comment: вот хороший пример такого расширеня ImageView http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/extendsImageView.htm